# Spyder IDE working fine, then crashed and won't load back up

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Let me preface this by saying I downloaded Spyder as part of the automatic installation of Anaconda about 2 months ago.

I was working on a web scraper in Spyder (i've written a few scrappers/files in Spyder before and run them with no issue).  However I accidentally dragged my file so that everything behind it was phased out, and tried to run my file.  It told me that I dragged the file out of my IPython environment, so I quit the application and tried to run it back up, hoping it would reconnect.

I've tried to open the application back up, and all I get is the spyder icon, followed by nothing.  I did the command line Spyder --reset and got this:

```
C:\Users\captainhukk>spyder --reset, and this is what I get in return:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 2, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 155, in <module>
    from spyderlib.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\environ.py", line 17, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditor import DictEditor
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditor.py", line 39, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditorutils import (sort_against, get_size,
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditorutils.py", line 78, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

Any ideas on what to do to fix this issue?  I am god awful at working with windows (always used a mac), and have been searching for answers for two hours now and feel completely lost.

Comment: As @gaFF mentioned, it seems you broke your installation by running `pip` in Anaconda. This is a bad practice, so please be careful about it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue in the html5library. Try to install the version 1.0b8, probably with (I encountered the same problem but on Linux) :

```
pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8
```